# tar extraction in iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

how can i extract tar file in iphone Sdk?i tried
both miniZip and libZ.dylib, it extracts only .gZ file. i decompressed **my.tar.gZ** file into **my.tar**.but how can i extract again tar file?any one can help?

Answer (score 2):

I've a home maid solution for you: https://github.com/mhausherr/Light-Untar-for-iOS

It's lighter than lib archive and may work for your use.

Complete discussion about that: http://blog.octo.com/en/untar-on-ios-the-pragmatic-way/

Answer (score 1):

The best library I've found is `libarchive`. It is well-designed, well-documented, and fast.

I just created a repository on GitHub that has the tools to build `libarchive` and `libbz2` as static libraries for iOS 4.2+. (It should be possible to use it to target 3.x, too.)

http://github.com/davepeck/iOS-libarchive/

In other related questions on Stack Overflow, people have pointed out that `libarchive` is included in the SDK. This is not quite true. The binary `libarchive.2.dylib` is included, but the headers are not. The same applies to `libbz2` (but, oddly, not to `libz`.) This means that `libarchive` is considered a private API -- in other words, you can't use it if you intend to ship on the App Store. Hence my repository.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [`libtar`](http://www.feep.net/libtar/#Download)?

Comment: is it possible in iphone SDK?it consists lot of files...
which one i have to use?READ ME file says to install it?

Comment: It's all C, looking at the lib and libtar folders, so you should be able to include these files in your project when compiling. This should work unless there is some special dependency. But it looks POSIX, as far as I can tell.